# edge triggered epoll missing 0 byte read on close

Tags: linux, networking, socket

I'm trying to understand if its possible to use edge-triggered epoll and avoid the need to call recv() to read from an epoll triggered READ event multiple times, every single time...

The epoll manpage says that for edge-triggered epoll, it is acceptable to stop reading from a socket if bytes_read is < bytes_requested, since the socket buffer is clearly exhausted and we can get back into the epoll_wait. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

> For stream-oriented files (e.g., pipe, FIFO, stream socket),
> the condition that the read/write I/O space is exhausted can
> also be detected by checking the amount of data read from /
> written to the target file descriptor.  For example, if you
> call read(2) by asking to read a certain amount of data and
> read(2) returns a lower number of bytes, you can be sure of
> having exhausted the read I/O space for the file descriptor.

However, I dont see how this gets around the socket close problem.

Say the server sends a client 128 bytes and immediately closes the socket.  Now the client was slow on the epoll_wait, and received the event for the data AND the close in one edge-triggered EPOLLIN event.  If I read that 128 bytes into say a 4k buffer, how can I avoid calling read again to check if the socket was closed?
According to the manpage, I dont have to call read again if I read less bytes than I asked for.  BUT, how does this account for the possibility that the socket was closed?

If I don't call read again, I can miss the close event all together.  Now it would appear that I HAVE to call read *at least* twice every time I get an ET EPOLLIN event... I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: Sounds like you're saying your epoll_wait returned (at least) EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP. If you then try to read 4K but only get 128, the EPOLLRDHUP is your clue that the connection is now half-closed, and further reads will return 0. If, unlike your description, the client's close (FIN) really hadn't arrived at the time of your read, then you would indeed need another read when the EPOLLRDHUP wakes epoll_wait up. (EPOLLIN will be set then too, btw).